# Persist addclass with cookies

Tags: jquery, cookies

I have a table and when i click on row i want to addclass .selectListItemReaded and persist on page refresh.

The plugin that i use it's https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

I have tried this code:

TABLE:

```
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" width="100%" id="tabelRezultat">
<tbody>
<tr class="selectListHeader">
<td class="selectListTitle inceput">Data cursei libere</td>
<td class="selectListTitle">Plecare din</td>
<td class="selectListTitle">Cursa spre</td>
<td class="selectListTitle">Locuri disponibile</td>
<td class="selectListTitle"></td>
</tr>   
<tr class="selectListItem" height="30">
<td class="rezultat inceput">test1</td>
<td class="rezultat">test2</td>
<td class="rezultat">test2</td>
<td class="rezultat">test3</td>
<td class="rezultat"><a class="clickBut" target="_blank" href="#">detalii</a></td>
</tr>
<tr class="selectListItem" height="30">
<td class="rezultat inceput"> another test1</td>
<td class="rezultat">another test2</td>
<td class="rezultat">another test2</td>
<td class="rezultat">another test3</td>
<td class="rezultat"><a class="clickBut" target="_blank" href="#">details</a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

SCRIPT TO MAKE AUTOMATIC ID FOR

```
jQuery(function ($) {

 var selectListItemDivs=$("tr.selectListItem");
 for(var i=0;i<selectListItemDivs.length;i++)
 { 
    $(selectListItemDivs[i]).attr("id","child-"+i);
 }

  var clickButDivs=$("a.clickBut");
 for(var i=0;i<clickButDivs.length;i++)
 { 
    $(clickButDivs[i]).attr("id","cursa-"+i);
 }

});
```

AND SCRIPT FOR ADD CLASS AND COOKIES (but it's not working)

```
jQuery(function ($) {


    var cookieName = 'up_';

    $('tr.selectListItem').click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id'), cookie = cookieName + id;
        //console.log($.cookie(cookie));
       if ($.cookie(cookie) !== 'true') {
        $(this).addClass('selectListItemReaded');
    }
    }).bind('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.cookie(cookieName + $(this).attr('id'), true);
    });
});
```

Can anybody help me with this ? I greatly appreciate your help .

Comment: How exactly is it "not working"?

Comment: Hello, that class selectListItemReaded don't remain on page reload. Thanks